# Ajax post JSON data to MVC getting error Unexpected token P

Tags: c#, ajax, json, excel, model-view-controller

This has been driving me nuts. I have a page where I need to make a JSON post to a controller, it will process it and return an excel file for download.  So far it appears to be running correctly, but when it returns to the ajax call, I get an parsererror and the message "Unexpected token P."  I have tried so many different configurations and call methods (standard MVC ActionRequest to WebApi post) and none of them change.  Here is the code I'm running.

JavaScript:

```
       var treatmentplan = {"PlanRecordStatusId":"1","PlanRecordDateBegin":"","PlanRecordDateEnd":"","ClientClaimNumber":"","PatientNumber":0,"requestAction":3};

        $.ajax({
            //global: true,
            //url: '/home/ExcelRpt',
            url: '/api/TreatmentPlanExcel',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: treatmentplan,
            //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                //var msg = data.Message;
                //$('#results').html(msg);
                $("#tmpFrame").attr('src', 'URL-TO-EXCEL-FILE');
            }
            , error: function (jqXHR, exception, error) {
                if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                    alert('Not connect.n Verify Network.');
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                    alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                    alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
                } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                    alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
                } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                    alert('Time out error.');
                } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                    alert('Ajax request aborted.');
                } else {
                    alert('Uncaught Error.n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                }
                $('#log').html(error.message);
            }
        });
```

Here is the C# code (both WebApi and MVC controller version), I am not going to include my ToExcel extension, I know this part works it's just a matter of getting it to download when it's returned.  It is reaching this code, generates data and returning.  I just need to see what the heck is going on.  If there is a prefered way of making the call, let me know as well (WebApi or MVC)

C#

Web Api version

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(TreatmentPlanRequest tpRequest) {
        tpRequest.Verify();
        List<TreatmentPlan> tpl = DataAccess.GetReportDap(tpRequest).ToList();

        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        var package = tpl.ToExcel("TreatmentReport");
        var fileStream = new MemoryStream();
        package.SaveAs(fileStream);
        fileStream.Position = 0;

        result.Content = new StreamContent(fileStream);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

        return result;

    }
```

Here is the MVC controller version

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ExcelRpt(TreatmentPlanRequest tpRequest) {
        tpRequest.Verify();            
        List<TreatmentPlan> tpl = DataAccess.GetReportDap(tpRequest).ToList();

        var contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        var package = tpl.ToExcel("TreatmentReport");
        var fileStream = new MemoryStream();
        package.SaveAs(fileStream);
        fileStream.Position = 0;

        var fsr = new FileStreamResult(fileStream, contentType);
        fsr.FileDownloadName = "TreatmentReport";

        return fsr;


    }
```

From here, I have no clue as to why this isn't working.  I have searched high and low on Google on how to do this in MVC (I use to do this with web forms and never had an issue).  I am guessing my issue is on the return or

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to thank Kris Hatcher for the solution on this.  He suggested making two ActionResults.  One that builds a query string from the parameters of the initial request.  It returns a full URL with the parameters.   It then does a Window.Open() using the returned url.

With all the examples I found, this was the only one that worked for me.  Here's how the code works.

JavaScript:

```
function TestWebApiReport() {
    var reportData = GetReport();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/home/ExcelResults'
        , data: reportData
        , type: 'POST'
        , dataType: 'json'
        , success: function (data) {
            window.open(data.URL);
        }, error: function (jqXHR, exception, error) {
            alert("GRRRRRR!!!")
        }
    });
}
```

It creates the JSON data, then posts it to a JsonResult.  Here's the controller code.

C#

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult ExcelResults(ReportRequest tpRequest) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        bool firstIn = true;
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}/Home/ExcelRpt", Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority);
        foreach (var prop in tpRequest.GetType().GetProperties()) {
            if (prop.GetValue(tpRequest, null) != null) {
                if (firstIn) {
                    sb.AppendFormat("?");
                    firstIn = false;
                } else {
                    sb.AppendFormat("&");
                }
                sb.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(tpRequest, null));
            }
        }

        return Json(new { URL = sb.ToString() }); 
    }
```

You go back to the JavaScript, you'll see the return data uses the URL to do a Window.Open().  Then the excel file is created.  Here's the last call (ActionResult).

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ExcelRpt(ReportRequest tpRequest) {

        if (tpRequest.requestAction != RequestAction.Report) {
            throw new Exception("Did not use action request type of 'Report'.");
        }
        tpRequest.requestAction = RequestAction.Report;
        List<Report> tpl = DataAccess.GetReportDap(tpRequest).ToList();

        var contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        var package = tpl.ToExcel("Report");
        var fileStream = new MemoryStream();
        package.SaveAs(fileStream);
        fileStream.Position = 0;

        var fsr = new FileStreamResult(fileStream, contentType);
        fsr.FileDownloadName = "TreatmentReport.xlsx";

        return fsr;
    }
```

ReportRequest is a class I have and ToExcel(), I extended the List item.  Now this works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Success method to open a new window with the URL instead of setting a frame in the current window.

So this:

```
$("#tmpFrame").attr('src', 'URL-TO-EXCEL-FILE');
```

becomes:

```
window.open('URL-TO-EXCEL-FILE');
```

In the vast majority of cases, this should do exactly what you're looking for.  Occasionally, depending on specific browser settings, users may get a "Popup Blocked" message, but that rarely happens in this scenario in the apps that I've worked with.

EDIT:

After additional clarification, there is a second issue.  Data returned from the server must be in the same format as the .ajax() method is expecting it, in this case 'JSON'.  Instead of returning a FileStreamResult from your Action, try returning a JSON object which has the URL you'll need to call to generate the Excel file.

```
return Json(new { URL = 'URL-TO-EXCEL-FILE' });
```

Then, follow the suggestion in my original response.

Comment: Right now it's not even hitting the success part, it keep returning back with a parseerror saying Unexpected Token P, which makes no sense to me.

Comment: You've told the $.ajax() method to expect JSON, but you're not returning a JSON object.

Comment: I'd recommend using the MVC method, but changing it from an 'ActionResult' to a 'JsonResult'.  Then, return a JSON object from the C# with the content you need instead of returning a FileStreamResult.

Comment: I thought the dataType is setting what the call format will be, is it supposed to be the return type? Every example I see regarding this has json in there.  Is there a dataType of excel or file?

Comment: You have to match the types between the JS and the C#.  If one is expecting JSON and the other is sending FileStream, things won't work right.

Comment: is there a dataType of excel or file in the js? Every example I've seen uses json

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72592/discussion-between-kris-hatcher-and-user779814).